# How do TYPE, LENGTHOF, and SIZEOF work for arrays and strings?

Tags: assembly, x86

Please,I need a help with this question. I am still a beginner with Assembly and I cant answer it.

Use the following data definitions for the next exercises:

```
.data

    myBytes BYTE 30h,70h,0A0h,60h
    myWords WORD 3 DUP(?),4000h
    myString BYTE "hello!!"
```

a)  What will be the value of EAX after each of the following instructions execute?

```
mov eax,TYPE myBytes     ; a. 
mov eax,LENGTHOF myBytes ; b. 
mov eax,SIZEOF myBytes   ; c. 
mov eax,TYPE myWords     ; d. 
mov eax,LENGTHOF myWords ; e.
mov eax,SIZEOF myWords   ; f. 
mov eax,SIZEOF myString  ; g.
```

Comment: What did you try? Did you at least try writing a program? We are not here to spoon feed you the answers

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This looks like MASM/TASM syntax, so consule the manual for either of those assemblers to find out the meaning of all those directives/operators.

Comment: Which assembler are you programming for?  What have you tried?  Can you show your attempt and your reasoning?

Comment: Thanks. I actually searched , but I can't understand every thing , cause  I am not an English native speaker. I think if i ask here , I will get more simple responses.

Answer (score 3):

From the page [MASM operators](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0140_type_lengthof_sizeof.htm) :
The **TYPE** operator returns the size (in bytes) of each element in an array.
The **LENGTHOF** operator returns the number of elements in an array.
The **SIZEOF** operator returns the number of bytes used by an array initializer.

Quick search for "MASM SIZEOF LENGTHOF" leads to this
[examples](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0141_masm_operators_htm.htm).