# Why every time is LENGTHOF set equal 1?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

Why every time is LENGTHOF set equal 1?
When if I did it separately for every set, it wouldn't be equally only just by 1.
I tried debugging it so many times, and I can't figure it out where I did a mistake.

```
TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
bodovanie DD 0, 100, 80, 60, 50, 45, 40, 36, 32, 29, 26, 24
Anna DD 2, 0, 1, 6, 6
Lena DD 4, 4, 7, 8, 3
Mikaela DD 1, 1, 5, 2, 1

nameA DB "Anna:",0
nameL DB "Lena:",0
nameM DB "Mikaela:",0
newline DB 0DH,0AH,0
.code
PriradenieBodov PROC mnozina:DWORD
    mov edx, mnozina
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov esi, 0
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF mnozina
    scitajBody:                 
        mov eax, mnozina[esi * 4]       
        add ebx, bodovanie[eax * 4]
        inc esi
        cmp esi, ecx
            je vypis
            jmp scitajBody
    vypis:
        ret

PriradenieBodov ENDP
main PROC
    invoke PriradenieBodov, Anna
    invoke PriradenieBodov, Lena
    invoke PriradenieBodov, Mikaela
    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Because `mnozina` is a `DWORD`. `LENGTHOF` is not a runtime construct.

Comment: Duplicate of [Calculate length of array inside procedure using offset passed through parameter, Assembly language x8086](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132150214) which only got (correctly) answered in comments.

Comment: See also [TYPE, LENGTHOF, SIZEOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960098/how-do-type-lengthof-and-sizeof-work-for-arrays-and-strings/69963018#69963018) SO answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, that was one I had answered a month ago. I misunderstood the question- I'll fix it now.